# How to use the postgres copy function in rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rake-task

I would like to copy a csv file to the production database (in a table without rails model). It's a large file with 130 000 rows. This files is in db/csv/datas.csv

I tryed to import with :

```
  CSV.foreach(Rails.root.join('db/csv/datas.csv'), headers: true) do |row|
  DataService.import(row.to_hash.symbolize_keys)
```

But it's very very long. Can I use the postgres copy function in a rake task ? Where must I put the csv file on the server ?

```
namespace :datas do
  desc 'datas import'
    task import_csv: :environment do
      copy_sql_cmd = <<-SQL
        COPY datas FROM 'db/csv/datas.csv' CSV HEADER;
      SQL

      ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
        ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(copy_sql_cmd)
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: You may be able to use this gem to shorten, simplify your copy task.  As for where to put the files, it's up to you. You can just pass the file path . 
 https://github.com/diogob/postgres-copy